# Что надо что бы сделать на сайте HTTPS?

Tags: https, asp.net-core-mvc

Я разрабатываю сайты на ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0, и меня интересует вопрос что нужно что бы сайт работал по HTTPS?

Я слышал что для того что бы получить сертификат HTTPS необходимо платить деньги каким-то компаниям, правда ли это, и если да, то зачем это нужно, и что мешает мне это сделать без оплаты?

Вопрос может показаться общим, но просто не знаю с чего начать, и как вообще понять нужен мне на сайте https, или вообще не нужен.

Comment: Можно получить бесплатный сертификат HTTPS Let's Encrypt

Comment: Вообще говоря нужно получить/купить сертификат и установить его на хостинге/сервере, вот и все

Comment: @demonplus слышал про такое, но не понимаю в чём смысл оплаты если можно сделать без оплаты? Или если без оплаты то браузер каждый раз на сертификат ругаться будет?

Comment: Ругаться не будет. Разница только в том, что бесплатный сертификат нужно каждые 90 дней обновлять, а платный можно купить на год или два

Comment: Сертификат HTTPS — это услуга сторонних компаний, которые проверяют и подтверждают, что вы действительно тот, за кого себя выдаёте. Естественно, за проверку могут попросить денежку, люди тратят время и ресурсы всё-таки. Проверки бывают разные: самая простая (и наименее безопасная) проверка домена проста и быстра и поэтому может быть бесплатной (см. вышеупомянутый Let's Encrypt), а Extended Validation с полной проверкой юридического лица долгая и дорогая, зато наиболее надёжная